# Why does adding \n at the end of my PS1 lead to substitution errors?

Tags: bash, git-bash, ps1

So, I'm on Windows and play around with my `PS1` for the Git bash.

My `PS1` looks like this:

```sh
PS1="\n\[\033[01;35m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] $PWD \[\033[00m\]\[\033[01;32m\]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")\[\033[00m\]\nλ "
```

Then I noticed that the branch name isn't updated when changing branches, and found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/896445), which tells me to exchange the double quotes for single quotes.

Now, my `PS1` looks like this:

```sh
PS1='\n\[\033[01;35m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] $PWD \[\033[00m\]\[\033[01;32m\]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")\[\033[00m\]\nλ '
```

Suddenly, I recieve warnings when executing my `.bashrc`:

```
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `__git_ps1 "(%s)")'
```

Further investigation shows me that when I remove the `\n` before the `λ` at the end of the `PS1` definition, the warning disappears.

Can anyone answer me:

- what does exactly cause this warning (the `\n` at the end seems totally unrelated to the execution of `__git_ps1` to me)?
- what do I need to change in order to remove the warning?

---

### Edit

When I change the `$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")` to `` `__git_ps1 "(%s)"` ``, the warning is gone and everything works as expected...

Comment: I suspect it is a problem with non-printing characters in the prompt that need to be escaped so the prompt can properly account for its length in the terminal. See [2.5. Bash Prompt Escape Sequences](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html) (last 2). I know there are better prompt tutorials that explain this better. You might search *"bash prompt escape non-printing characters"* and see if you can find a detailed explanation. If the prompt does not properly account for its length, all kind of strange things happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution

```sh
NEWLINE="
"
PS1='\[\033[01;35m\]\u@\h \[\033[01;34m\]$PWD\[\033[01;32m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[00m\]$NEWLINEλ '
```

There is trouble involved in the newline being around, also resetting the color was making the line longer than necessary.

Smallest sample of problem:

```sh
PS1='$(date)\n$'
```

Looks like an issue with variable substitution.